# EF7 Error insert Default Date

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, default

I'm using EF7 with SQLite and define my class like this:

```
 class LogMessage
{
    public LogMessage()
    {

    }

    public DateTime? MessageDate { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }

}
```

in the OnModelCreating I specify the default value like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<LogMessage>()
            .Property(m => m.MessageDate).HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");
```

When I check the Database I got this structure that Looks fine to me:

```
CREATE TABLE "LogMessage" 
(
"MessageDate" TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) CONSTRAINT "PK_LogMessage" PRIMARY KEY,
"Body" TEXT
)
```

But when I'm trying to add something to the entity with this code:

```
result = "a";
Message = new LogMessage();
Message.Body = result;
context.LogMessages.Add(Message);
context.SaveChanges();
```

I get this error:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'Microsoft.Data.Entity.DbUpdateConcurrencyException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.Core.dll Additional information: Database operation
>   expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may
>   have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded

Any idea about why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**Auto-Implemented Properties**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) as shown below.

```
 class LogMessage
{
    public LogMessage()
    {

    }

    public DateTime? MessageDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public string Body { get; set; }

}
```